# Order by child collection in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Entity Framework model that looks like:

```
public class User
{
  public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
  publc virtual List<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
  public string ModelType {get;set;}
}
```

**Now I want to get all the users, and order by DESC so that users that have cars with the ModelType of "Sedan" are at the top.**

In my query I am doing some eager loading by including the property "Cars", but I am not sure how to order by for a child property.

I am using the Generic Repository pattern based on this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

My method is currently like this:

```
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return Get(orderBy: o => o.OrderByDescending(u => u.DateCreated), 
            includeProperties: "Cars").ToList();
    }
```

So it has a Get method that looks like:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

the idea would be

```
OrderByDescending(u => u.Cars.Any(c => c.ModelType == "Sedan"));
```

(little doubt with boolean, I think it should be OrderByDescending, but... I let you check.)